# set mod rewrite for subdomain url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to make beauthy URL address with mod rewrite. I am using subdomain and my page who I want to change is : 
http://skola.sharedgames.eu/subdom/skola/clanky/podrobnosti_o_clanku.php?nazov_clanku=jjjhh

I want to make something like : 
http://skola.sharedgames.eu/subdom/skola/clanky/jjjhh

I tried make it in to .htaccess file but nothing happend

```
# htaccess rules for subdomains and aliases
# to create new subdomain, create a folder www/subdom/(subdomain name)
# to create web for alias, create a folder www/domains/(whole domain name)


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\?$ /subdom/skola/clanky/podrobnosti_o_clanku.php?nazov_clanku=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

Comment: that's not a subdomain. that's a subDIRECTORY. a subdomain would be something involving the host/domain  name, e.g. `example.com` -> `subsite.example.com`

Comment: But it is subdomain, because I have domain "sharedgames.eu" and then subdomain "skola.sharegames.eu"

Comment: yes, but you're not changing anything about the subdomain. you're just changing the query string stuff. that's nothing to do with subdomains.

Comment: Ou I understand, so I changed it only for main domain. So you know how I change it for subdomain?